# ASP.Net Auto Jump to Next TextField

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code, how can I make the cursor to autojump to the next textfield in this case the dd when the user enters a two digit in the month textbox?

```
<p>  
   <h5>Date of Birth <font color="red">* </font>(mm/dd/yyyy)</h5>

   <asp:TextBox ID="mm" runat="server"  MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="dd" runat="server"  MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:TextBox ID="yyyy" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>

 </p>
```

Comment: do you what server side or client side ??

Comment: it does not matter anyway works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function ChangeFocus()
{
    if($("#txtboxDay").val().length==2)
        {
            $("#txtboxmonth").focus();
        }

}
 $("#txtboxDay").bind("change",ChangeFocus);

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but where do I put the code? I apologize I am newbie in ASP.NET

Comment: You can  put the code in a .js file and take reference in your asp.net web page. Alternative you can write down jQuery code in your aspx page itself (but it's not a good practice).